# a cake of ice melting in the sun

Tags: phrase-meaning

I understand the phrase "our atomic monopoly is like a cake of ice melting in the sun" as "our atomic monopoly will soon disappear." (Because a cake of ice melting in the sun will vaporize very soon).  Am I on the right track?

> Robert Oppenheimer told the Time magazine: "our atomic monopoly is like a cake of ice melting in the sun."

> Source: The Untold History of the United States pp 223

Comment: It's a very simple analogy. It means the dominance (being the first to produce the atom bomb) will obviously (as  ice melts in the sun) disappear.

Comment: Hi there, yes I'd say you're right, but this kind of question isn't really suitable for the site. You're basically asking "am I right?" and the answer can only be yes or no.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a simile and you can infer what you want from it.  THe "atomic monopoly" clearly refers to the state (at that time) in which only the USA had atomic bombs.

Like a cake of ice suggests that it going quickly, and can't be stopped, and can't be reversed.  Some similies are idiomatic, or even cliché, but this seems to have been an invention of Oppenheimer (who was highly intelligent, articulate and skillful with words and ideas)